# Ошибка при авторизации PMA

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache2

Гуглил, на ютубе смотрел и зря. Проблема у меня такая при авторизации в PMA выдает 2 ошибки:

> Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL, mysqli_real_connect():(HY000/1698): 
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.

Я уже давал все права и менял файл *config.sample.inc.php* - Безрезультатно...

Сам конфиг менял (правил `password=''` и `user='root'`. Рестартил Mysql и переустанавливал PMA. У меня линукс, если что.

Comment: В mysql есть отличие от подключения к *localhost* и *127.0.0.1*. Попробуйте 127.0.0.1

Comment: ArchDemon не помогло((

Comment: Попробуй зайти не через root, а через юзера с нужными правами.
[Мне тут помог первый способ](https://zalinux.ru/?p=1135), а второй на крайний случай.